# Combination of different sorts

Tags: permutations, combinations

I am little bit confused with the following question below. I need your help. No it is not a homework. Just exercise for my exam.

**Question:**
There is a bottle box can take 9 bottles max. how many possibilities there are in order to fill the complete if  there are 5 different drinks(bottles)? we assume that from each bottle sort there are enough bottles and it doesn't matter in which place bottle will be places.

**my Thoughts:**

I am thinking that i should use combination here as the order doesn't matter. Is it C(9 5)=126 or c(45 9) - because it says that there are enough bottles for each sort which should 45 bottles max.

thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_1$ be the number of bottles of flavor $1$ we put into the box.  Similarly, $x_2, \dots, x_5$ will be the number of bottles of flavors $2,\dots,5$ respectively.

A rephrasing of the question is then to find the number of nonnegative integer solutions to the following system:

$\begin{cases} x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=9\\
0\leq x_1\\
0\leq x_2\\
0\leq x_3\\
0\leq x_4\\
0\leq x_5\end{cases}$

This is a well known problem type.  If you have seen it already, then you can jump straight to the answer.  If you *haven't* seen this problem type before, then consider the following:

Let us take $9$ "stars" and lay them in a row as well as four "bars".  The number of stars to the left of the first bar will represent the number $x_1$.  The number of stars inbetween the first and second bar will represent the number $x_2$, continuing up to $x_5$ being represented by the number of stars to the right of the fourth bar.

For example the sequence $\star\mid\mid\star\star\star\star\mid\star\mid\star\star\star$ represents having taken one bottle of flavor $1$, zero bottles of flavor $2$, four bottles of flavor $3$, one bottle of flavor $4$, and three bottles of flavor $5$.

The sequence $\star\star\star\star\star\star\star\star\star\mid\mid\mid\mid$ represents having taken nine bottles of flavor one and no other flavors.

You should be able to convince yourself that these sequences of stars and bars are in direct bijection to the number of ways of picking the values of $x_1,x_2,\dots$ which is in turn in direct bijection with the number of ways of filling your case of sodas.  It should be much easier to count the number of sequences.

> Pick which $4$ of the $13$ positions are occupied by the bars, and the remaining $9$ positions will be occupied by stars.

In general, for the system:$\begin{cases} x_1+x_2+\dots+x_r = n\\
0\leq x_1\\
\vdots\\
0\leq x_r\end{cases}$

> there are a total of $\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}=\binom{n+r-1}{n}$ number of solutions.

This is such a common problem type that it receives its own symbol:  $\left(\!\!\binom{r}{n}\!\!\right)$