# How many 40-multisets

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Consider the collection formed by the letters of the **English alphabet** and the numbers from **1 to 9.**

How many **40-multisets** are there that have **at most 10 letters?**

I am assuming this is going to be solved by looking at combinations with repetition.
Would the Answer be  P(40; 26, 10)?

Comment: By 40-multisets, I assume you mean multisets of size 40.  E.g. $\{1,1,2,3,3\}$ has size five.  I don't expect this to simplify nicely, but perhaps try looking at it via cases: exactly zero letters appear, exactly one letter appears, ... exactly 10 letters appear.

Comment: When you prescribe at most ten letters, is this counting letters with repetition or only counting the number of distinct letters?

Comment: This is all of the information given, though I would assume this will include repetition making this number gigantic.

Comment: Okay, I will assume the "at most ten letters" includes any repeated letters counted according to their multiplicity..

Answer (score 0):

By "have at most 10 letters," I assume you mean 10 letters with repetition total as opposed to 10 distinct letters.

If we break it up via cases based on how many letters there are exactly, we have the possibilities that zero letters appear, one letter appears, ... up until 10 letters appear.

To count one of these cases, say for example exactly five letters appearing, first pick which five letters appear and then pick which numbers appear.

Approach this via stars-and-bars/balls-and-urns/...

Letting $x_a=\#\text{of a's picked},x_b=\#\text{of b's picked},\dots$ we have the system:

$\begin{cases} x_a+x_b+\dots+x_z=5\\0\leq x_a\\ 0\leq x_b\\ \vdots\\ 0\leq x_z\end{cases}$

There are then $\binom{5+26-1}{26-1}$ number of ways of picking which five letters appear.

Similarly, there are $\binom{35+9-1}{9-1}$ number of ways of picking the remaining 35 elements of our multiset.

This gives us exactly $\binom{30}{25}\binom{43}{8}$ possible multisets with exactly five letters.

Generalize this number to an arbitrary number of letters picked and sum over all cases to arrive at a final answer.

Comment: where is the -1 coming from in the calculations?

Comment: @John have you not seen stars and bars before?  See my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1537646/combination-of-different-sorts/1537667#1537667) where I explain how to calculate the multichoose function.  The minus ones are coming from the fact that we need one fewer bar than the number of urns in order to fully describe the scenario using stars and bars.

Answer (score 0):

One approach (assuming, as JMoravitz did, that the ten letters includes any repetitions of letters) is to use a transition matrix which tracks the state of how many letters are used.

Initially there is a state of no letters used, then 40 characters are drawn with "uniform probability" from the $26$ letters and $9$ digits available (so thirty-five possibilities with each draw).  The possible states we will track are $12$ in all, from no letters, one letter, two letters, and so on up to ten letters and finally eleven or more letters. [This last state is "absorbing".]

The (integer normalized) transition matrix will thus be:

$$ M = \begin{bmatrix} 9 & 26 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 9 & 26 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 9 & 26 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 9 & 26 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 9 & 26 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 9 & 26 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 9 & 26 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 9 & 26 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 9 & 26 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 9 & 26 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 9 & 26 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 35 \end{bmatrix} $$

Letting $u = [1 \; 0 \; 0 \;\ldots \; 0]$ represent the initial distribution (count) of states (prior to drawing any characters), the final distribution will be given by:

$$ u M^{40} $$

whose first eleven entries are those with "at most ten letters" and whose twelfth and final entry counts those with more than ten letters.  The computation may be slightly simplified by omitting the last row and column of $M$ (and the last entry of $u$), since the twelfth entry added to the preceding ones must total a known count of $35^{40}$.

The computation can be carried out (say in double precision floating point) easily enough by binary exponentiation.  However the "truncated" version of $M$ (dropping last row and column) is simply $9I$ plus a nilpotent matrix, and it may be feasible to carry out the computation semi-symbolically.